# Problems scheduling a task on windows7

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I have trouble to schedule a task I wrote.

Basically I created a `.bat` file which executes an R script (`script.R`). When I double click the `.bar` file, it gets executed. I can see a result file and also some kind of log file in `script.Rout`.

When I try to run everything in the scheduler I have problem to get it to run. When I click on `Run` to run my task, the task produces several entries in the `History` tab which shows my task starts, and also ends in the same second. So basically nothing gets executed.

Where can I check what problem occurs? My script writes some output which is located within this `.Rout` file but this is not created with the task scheduler.

I already added my user to the policy settings to schedule task and also by editing the task, windows does not complain, I think this is not the issue.

Would love to get some help to find the problem.

**EDIT:**

I realised now, my task is running as long I do not select `Execute task whether user is logged in or not`. If I switch to this setting, my script does not get executed. Is there maybe some security issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Task Scheduler Scheduled Batch Script Not Running Check

**Task Scheduler Properties. . .**

From Windows `Task Scheduler` on the job **<kbd>properties</kbd>** *(see bottom most screen shots)* in the. . .

- **1.** **<kbd>General</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are select/checked or unchecked just as shown in **Print Screen A**

  - *Uncheck* `Run only when user is logged on`
  - *Check* `Run whether user is logged on or not`
  - *Check* `Run with the highest privileges`
- **2.** **<kbd>Conditions</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are **select**, **checked**, or **unchecked** just as shown in **Print Screen B**

  - *Check* `Wake the computer to run this task`
- **3.** **<kbd>Actions</kbd>** tab, click **<kbd>Edit</kbd>**, and enure that the `Start in (optional)` is set just as shown in the below example (**DO NOT** put double quote marks around it) for the full path pointing where the batch script is located **WITHOUT** a final backslash "`\`" **Print Screen C**

---

### **Security Considerations**

- *Once you press **<kbd>OK</kbd>** (**2.** above) it should prompt you for the credential to run this as, and that credential is what will need access to **`EXECUTE`** the batch file where it exist, and it will also need access to do whatever the batch file is running that you scripted out.*
- *It may be best to setup a static service/proxy user account for this process and then use its credentials to run the process. You'd need to ensure its password is strong and it set to never expire—and it needs access to **`EXECUTE`** the batch and run whatever the batch scripted process is running and any commands and resources, ect. it utilizes as well.*
- It seems the option `Run whether user is logged on or not` you MUST
  check the option `Run with highest privileges` for it to actually
  run as expected from the Task Scheduler.

**Error Checking**

- If there is an issue with the actual batch script but the Windows **Task
  Scheduler** actually does execute it to run it but the batch script
  logic errors out, etc. for whatever reason, the **Task Scheduler** may
  not see this failure at this level. From its perspective (by default most of the time), it’s
  executing the batch file so as long as it can execute it and has
  access to do so, its job is done successfully.
- Add **error checking** or **logging** to the batch script logic to **catch** (or **troubleshoot**) issues at this level including ensuring that the security context which the batch scheduler executes it as has appropriate access to commands, resources, etc. which the batch script runs as.

---

### Group Policy Considerations

[**CHECK GROUP POLICY AND LOG ON AS A BATCH JOB PERMISSIONS**](http://www.brooksnet.com/faq/117-02.html)

> **Answer:** *On Windows, this privilege is granted through the **Local** or **Domain Security Policy**. To do this using the **Local Security Policy**,
>   follow these steps.*
>
> 1. In the **Control Panel**, open **Administrative Tools**, then **Local Security**
>      Policy.
> 2. Beneath **Security Settings**, open **Local Policies** and highlight **User
>      Rights Assignment**.
> 3. Locate **Log on as a batch job**. Open the **properties** and add any users
>      that need this right.
> 4. When finished, **save** your changes and close the **Local Security
>      Settings** window.
>
> Your changes should take effect immediately. To make changes to the
>   Domain Security Policy, on a domain controller, use the **Domain
>   Security Policy utility** in the **Control Panel**

---

### Batch Script Logic with Mapped Drives or Full UNC Path, and issues. . .

If your script is referencing a mapped network drive but you want it to `Run whether the user is logged on or not`, then under this context, the drive mapping may not actually be there for the batch process to do what’s expected.

If possible, use `UNC` paths in your batch script logic rather than a mapped drive letter to avoid issues.  Otherwise, you may need to use `PUSHD \\ServerName\ShareName` at the beginning of the batch process and then use `POPD` at the end of the batch process. You could map the drive with `NET USE X: \\ServerName\ShareName` at the beginning of the batch process and then disconnect the drive with `NET USE X: /DELETE` at the end of the batch process.

- [**NET USE**](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html)
- [**PUSHD**](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- [**POPD**](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

---

### OTHERS

- [**MS HOTFIX (KB977353): Group Policy Immediate Task preference item does not run on a client computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977353)

---

**PRINT SCREENS**

**Print Screen A**

[image]

**Print Screen B**

[image]

**Print Screen C**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very quick help. I basically checked all your suggestions, only the `Run with highest privileges` is not possible to set, even as administrator. It always complains my permission is not high enough. Actually this is a domain computer and I have a local Administrator which should be sufficient enough I thought. The policies where checked, only the `Start in` option produces and error on starting the script. But again, I don't find log files on the exact error. The `History` just says Event 103 or 203. Run and Launch Failure.

Comment: I guess I found the problem. My script accesses a network drive which is not (or is not easy to) mounted when I am logged out. That might be the reason why the logged in user can execute the task. Since I am not able to mount the files in my script, I guess this is how it is. But thanks for your help! On a lokal system you answer helped.

Comment: I found this post most comprehensive on this topic, but still my computers are not awake from sleep, I'm trying on HP Elite G2 800 SSF with Windows 10 Pro any idea that i have to setup in BIOS?

Comment: @sairfan Elevated cmd, run `powercfg /hibernate off` reboot and then see if that helps. Maybe it is hibernating rather than sleeping at the OS level, see if that helps for a starting point.