# Automatically send multiple emails from Outlook at specific times

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, automation

I have a need to send an email every 10 seconds for about 2 minutes, but I'd like to schedule this to occur starting at a specific time (8:59) and ending near a specific time (9:01).

I need to ensure that an email is sent starting at 8:59 for the first one and send the same email again every 10 seconds (interval-wise) but I need it to end at 9:01 or so.

I use Outlook for my email client software and I'm a local administrator on my PC—I am not the network administrator if that makes any difference to anyone.

Does anyone know of a program or method of accomplishing this task? I'm fine with using an application that can do this or that can change the time-stamp perhaps as well.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE internal

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE 2016, I'm admin on my machine but I'm not a network admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Automatically send multiple emails from Outlook at specific times**
>
> I have a need to send an email every 10 seconds for about 2 minutes,
>   but I'd like to schedule this to occur starting at a specific time
>   (8:59) and ending near a specific time (9:01).
>
> I need to ensure that an email is sent starting at 8:59 for the first
>   one and send the same email again every 10 seconds (interval-wise) but
>   I need it to end at 9:01 or so.

Below I have listed TWO options for automatically sending emails at specific times

### Use sendEmail, Batch Script, and Windows Task Scheduler

One way (at the bottom of my answer) is with scheduling a batch
    script to send on a custom schedule with **Windows Task Scheduler**
    with the
    [**sendEmail**](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)
    application.

I setup the batch script logic below for the **sendEmail** script to have a counter in it that *starts at 0 and ends at 12 with about 10 seconds between each next higher digit counting up by 1*.

***(This means you will want to start this script at the exact time and second you want it to start and it'll send every 10 seconds up until 2 minutes (e.g. 8:59:00 AM) after that point.)***

[image]

It appears **Windows Task Scheduler** doesn't get as granular with scheduling or triggering a task to the second (one minute interval seems to be it's limit). I put a 120 second timer in the batch script logic below, and it'll send an email every 10 seconds until it counts to 120 seconds (or two minutes) and then end.

### Getting sendEmail Ready and Scheduled with Batch Script

### [sendEmail Information](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

- [***sendEmail (No TLS) - Download***](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/sendEmail-v156-notls.zip)
- [***sendEmail (with TLS) - Download***](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/sendEmail-v156.zip)

**Scheduled Batch Script with sendEmail**

*(You should be able to get away with the above **"No TLS"** download and exe for the **sendEmail** application that you'll schedule for sending emails with a batch script, calling it via command line, and scheduling it with [**Windows Task Scheduler**](https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216)—If you have trouble or need to authenticate with TLS, I'll add an example script how to do it that way as well if needed.)*

*(When you download the Zip file from the links provided, just put the `exe` in a Windows directory in your `PATH` environmenal variable (i.e. `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`) or call it **full path** explictly (e.g. `"C:\SendEmail\sendEmail.exe"`). The example batch script logic expects it in a `PATH` environmental variable location. If you need logic to point to it explicitly, tell me the full path where you need to reference the `exe` and I'll add an example that way too.)*

```
@ECHO OFF
::: --// Set the counter variable to zero when script begins
SET Counter=0
GOTO :okNowReallySendEmail

:SendEmail
::: --// Add 1 to counter variable to know when it gets to 12 for every 10 seconds is two minutes 8:59 - 9:01
SET /A Counter=%Counter%+1

::: --// Ping delay to loopback roughly 10 second count
PING -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL

::: --// End if counter is 12 as that's 12 times 10 which equals 120 seconds roughly
IF %Counter%==12 GOTO EOF

:okNowReallySendEmail
SET EMAILSERVER=emailserver.domain.com
SET subject=This is my subject
SET FromAddress=YourEmailAddress@Domain.com
SET ReplyAddress=YourEmailAddress@Domain.com
SET ToAddress=ToEmailAddress@Domain.com
SET EMAILBODY1=This is my email body paragraph1
SET EMAILBODY2=This is my email body paragraph2
SET Signature=My Name
SENDEMAIL -f %FromAddress% -t %ToAddress% -u %subject% -m "%EMAILBODY1%<br />  <br />%EMAILBODY2%<br />  <br />%Signature%" -s %EMAILSERVER%:25 -o message-content-type=html reply-to=%ReplyAddress%
GOTO :SendEmail
```

### Task Scheduler

See this answer here for full details of what options you should pick when scheduling this job with **Windows Task Scheduler** ⇒ [**Options to Select with Task Scheduler Job Setup**](https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216)

*(Don't forget to upvote this answer if helpful as well)*

---

### Use Outlook Delay or Schedule Sending Messages

The second way is with Outlook (2010 and 2013) using the ***Delay or schedule sending messages*** feature that is a little less specific on the time scheduling part (not by the second either).

When you tell Outlook not send before a certain time on a certain date, it'll send as soon as Outlook's outbox emails try to send queue items out when it's that time or later when it's triggered.

I have seen email sent via this method keep the date and time stamp of the actually time you sent these options and press <kbd>Send</kbd> rather than the time you told it to not run before. When you press <kbd>Send</kbd> to send it out, it just sits in an Outlook outbox queue until that time but not before.

[image]

### [**Outlook 2013**](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-253dbfd7-0db7-4f41-bcc5-9e8e68ae29bf)

[image: Outlook 2013]

### [**Outlook 2010**](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=44266)

[image: Outlook 2010]

Comment: How would it be better to use SendEmail instead of Outlook?

Comment: I used the delay sending option in Outlook on a few messages I had drafted. Thanks!