# How to create scheduled task of a batch file (Windows)?

Tags: windows, batch, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file containing something like this

`C:\Python27\Scripts\twistd.py -n -y C:\Program Files (x86)\POS\atidps.py
pause`

How to create scheduled task to run at startup (to all user including non admin), with the command prompt windows always appear, as like when I run the batch script. So it should gonna be like [this](http://prntscr.com/bzj6c4).

I'm new in Windows system administration things, so any detailed answer will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This thread has the details you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler . See also http://www.digitalcitizen.life/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler

Comment: @w32sh Great! Don't have idea why he posted it on SO, haha. It should be migrated here. Thank you!

Comment: See here for more details on this type of a task for common issues: http://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216 You want a trigger to use **At Logon for Any User** or **At Startup** it sounds to me. If you want it to show at logon then do the at logon otherwise at startup it'll run when Windows starts up.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Superb! Actually I'm just want to post question about NET USE printer share permission issue. But your answer there seems what I was gonna look for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found better solution. Make twisted application as Windows Service using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc).

More detailed 'How To' can be found from [this blog post part 2](http://www.christianlong.com/blog/twisted-on-windows-2015-edition-part-2.html). There are 3 part articles. It is quite useful, rather than make scheduled task.