# mysql command using task scheduler in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

have a script which stops and start the replication in MySQL. I am able to run this command in command prompt but unable to setup in task scheduler of windows. In CMD I'm using below step to run query: cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\ mysql.exe -u root -proot < C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.sql

In test.sql I have added queries which I want to execute. In task scheduler I have added below action:
[enter image description here][1]
Can someone help to setup this in windows task scheduler. Need help to add action in task scheduler.

Comment: Check items from this answer and see if it helps you any. Feel free to give it an upvote if you find it helpful. http://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216

Comment: The image is missing.