# Trigger an action on a Windows machine from an Android phone via network

Tags: windows, batch, android

### My Problem

I have an Internet connection in my house and many of my friends come over everyday and always want to use my notebook to access the Internet.

I don't want to be mean and tell them no that they cannot use my notebook to browse the Internet so often as this may have negative consequences with my friendships with these people.

I would like to disrupt their experience remotely from my Android phone connected to the same local network as the **Windows** machine someway in a secretive manner.

---

### My Idea

I have software on my Android phone, and I setup a shared folder on the **Windows 7** machine and confirmed I can create and delete files in this location from my Android when connected on the same network.

I need a way to utilize this shared folder and trigger some sort of task or batch script on the **Windows** machine from my Android as needed that will disrupt the network of my notebook.

If I can get the network on the notebook to be disrupted or something then this would trick people into thinking the notebook doesn't work very well at all and they'd stop asking to use so often.

---

### **Question**

I already know how to make a batch file that makes a computer freeze but I'm not sure where to start to trigger a batch script or something to run on the **Windows** machine with the shared folder access I have from the Android to create and delete files. Any way to help make this task possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64267/discussion-on-question-by-stiev-trigger-an-action-on-a-windows-machine-from-an-a).

Comment: @Stiev .... Curious to hear how this worked or has been working out for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you already have a solution to access a shared folder from your Android phone and confirmed you can access it and delete files, I'll give you the steps to take to setup a batch script on the **Windows** machine that will simply check for a file there and then take an action based on the conditional [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic.

- If the file does not exist then it'll disable a network adapter based on interface name.
- If the file does exist then it will exit and not do anything after that.

You will need to use **Task Scheduler** and use specific settings to ensure the process runs in a hidden manner so it's not visible on the screen when the batch script is executed.

If you want to disable the Network Adapter remotely, connect to the shared folder with your Android phone and simply delete the file. Now every time the batch script is executed it'll disable that NIC.

---

### Prerequisite - Time for some detective work

Get the *name of the [interface] Network Adapter* you wish to disable by running this in an admin elevated command prompt: `netsh interface show interface`. Take note of the "***Interface Name***" of the network adapter which you wish to disable via command line with the batch script.

I will disable the "***Ethernet***" named adapter in the examples I provide. You will obviously need to replace this value with the applicable name of the interface in your environment to disable.

[image]

[image]

---

### Batch Script to Schedule

Be sure to set the values of the `SET Folder=` and `SET File=` to equal the valid folder path and file name that the batch file will check whether or not it exists with the conditional [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic.

Be sure to also set the value of the `SET IntName=` to be the value of the Interface Name of the network adapter the batch script will disable.

**Example Script (zDisableNic.cmd)**

```
@ECHO ON

SET Folder=C:\SomeFolder
SET File=start.txt
SET IntName=Ethernet

:Routine
SET var=%Folder%\%File%
IF EXIST "%var%" EXIT

netsh int set int "%IntName%" admin=disable
EXIT
```

---

You can keep a small batch file in a (or the same) folder if you want to right-click on and select run as administrator to enable the NIC manually quickly as you need to.

Once you create the `start.txt` file to ensure the other batch file does not disable the NIC, you then right-click and run as administrator on the **EnableNic** batch script.

**Example Script (zEnableNIC.cmd)**

```
:: Where "Ethernet" is the applicable "Interface Name" value from the result of the `netsh interface show interface` command
SET IntName=Ethernet
netsh int set int "Ethernet" admin=enable
```

---

### Task Scheduler

From Windows `Task Scheduler` on the job **<kbd>`Properties`</kbd>** *(See below **Print Screens**)*

- **1.** In the **<kbd>`General`</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are select/checked or unchecked just as shown in the Print Screen **"General"**

  - *Uncheck* `Run only when user is logged on`
  - *Check* `Run whether user is logged on or not`
  - *Check* `Run with the highest privileges`
- **2.** In the **<kbd>`Triggers`</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are set just as specified and shown in the Print Screen **"Triggers"**

  - *Begin the task:* `On a schedule`
  - *Settings:* `One time`
  - *Repeat task* `every 1 minutes`
  - *for a duration of* `indefinitely`
  - *Check* `Wake the computer to run this task`
- **3.** In the **<kbd>`Action`</kbd>** tab, click **<kbd>`Edit`</kbd>**, and ensure that the below options are set just as specified and shown in the Print Screen "**Action**"

  - the `Program/script` value should be the the full path where the batch script is located **without** a final backslash "`\`" but with double quotes around it
  - the `Start in (optional)` value should be set just as shown in the below example—**do not** put double quote marks around this value though
- **4.** Once you press **<kbd>`OK`</kbd>** (maybe twice) you will be prompted for a credential as shown in Print Screen "**Credential**"

  - I created a new user account named `service` on my machine and gave it a strong password, ensured the account was enabled, was set with a password that never expires, and was a local administrator on the machine—you can tighten down more granular I'm sure if needed—and this is the credential I used here

---

### Print Screens

**General**

[image]

**Triggers**

[image]

**Action**

[image]

**Credential**

[image]

---

> ### In the end
>
> So, essentially after you complete the steps as described
>   above you should end up with a configuration as described below:
>
> 1. Two batch scripts; one that's scheduled to disable a NIC and another to run manually as-needed to enable a NIC
>
>    [image]
> 2. **One scheduled task to execute the batch script once a minute**
>
>    [image]
> 3. **One file to create and delete as needed**
>
>    [image]
>
> ### **Trigger Notebook NIC Disable Operation**
>
> This means if the file of **C:\Test\start.txt** does not exist then the batch
>   script that runs once a minute **will** disable the NIC disrupting its network connectivity. If the
>   file does exist then the batch script will exit doing nothing further. The folder the "start" file resides in should be the same folder that you setup the share on and accessed from the Android already.
>
> Since you confirmed you can delete a file on notebook Windows shared folder
>   from your Android, you simply connect and delete this file as needed
>   and you can be assured that once a minute the batch script will
>   disable the NIC when executed.
>
> ### Preventing Notebook NIC Disable Operation
>
> When you get back to the machine and you need to use the Internet, you
>   simply go to the **C:\Test** folder (or whatever you decide to use), right-click, **New** | **Text
>   Document** | name it **start.txt** (or whatever you decide to use) and then right-click run the
>   `zEnableNIC.cmd` (from the folder you put that script) as administrator and the NIC will be re-enabled and you
>   can use the Internet again without disruption from the batch script
>   that still runs once a minute.

---

### Further Resources

- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Command Line Disable NIC - Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/script-to-disable-enable-network-interface/8eb15e24-7d85-4a16-b42a-a874b9bb3a28?auth=1)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Share a Folder or Drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [Schedule a Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspxx)
- [Task Scheduler Scheduled Batch Script Not Running Check](https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216)