# Force login when "The task you are trying to do can't be completed because remote desktop services is currently busy" happens?

Tags: remote-desktop

Let's say I am the sole user of a remote computer, meaning no one else will try to connect to the computer, and I only use one account to log into the computer using Remote Desktop. Sometimes RD hangs. Then I close RD and launch RD again, and try to connect to the server.

Often, `The task you are trying to do can't be completed because remote desktop services is currently busy` happens and I cannot log in. I cannot access the local screen of the computer, so I cannot restart the computer or the remote desktop process.

Is there any way to forcibly log into computer with RD? I do not mind forcibly disconnecting or killing previous connection(s), because those are also my connections.

Comment: Are you able to connect as "Administrator" for that purpose? This will allow you to close your user session, or the specific task

Comment: You could try connecting to the machine with [PSExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) then restart the remote desktop service (sorry, on mobile & don't remember its name).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator termsrv is the name of the service

Comment: @DamnVegetables Check out my answer here where if you can access your machine also via FTP and there is a folder you can upload or delete a file then you can trigger any action really.... https://superuser.com/questions/1242506/trigger-an-action-on-a-windows-machine-from-an-android-phone-via-network/1243112#1243112. I suppose you could use the applicable `NET STOP <servicename>` command for the service or the `SHUTDOWN /R /T 01`, etc. If it's important enough to you, I think this would be a simple solution potentially. Happy to help if you ask if I have time.