# Windows 10: bat files not being run when double clicked

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, console

somethings has been changed in my win10 pro (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.134]) box, and now I have issues with bat files:

1. when I double click on them, I get a cmd, empty that shows up for a couple of seconds, and then closes. The .bat is NOT run
2. if I open a cmd can cd to the dir containing the .bat, and I type the first letters of the .bat, TAB does not complete the file name, it does complete filenames of exe files.
3. if I run the .bat from the cmd I opened in 2., it DOES run fine
4. I have checked "assoc .bat" and "ftype batfile" and both return expected values.

Any insight would be super useful...

Comment: Read over the detail from this in detail and triple and quadruple check the things talked about all all these levels—https://superuser.com/questions/1005192/problems-scheduling-a-task-on-windows7/1005216#1005216—and don't forget to not overlook anything.

Comment: actually, found the issue, I had an Autorun configured at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor that was the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: You should consider adding an answer with thorough detail explaining everything regarding your solution to ensure your solution helps others with this question then.